# C++ Reading File with bunzip2

Tags: c++

```
#include<fstream>

int main()
{
    ifstream fFeedList;
    fFeedList.open("/ra/file");

    return 0;
}
```

How to read files with .bz2  in C++? Thanks!!

Comment: Your SSCCE is rather, err, rudimentary.

Comment: I never read bz2 file before. how to read it in C++? thanks!!

Comment: You could use the C interface in libbzip2 as documented [here](http://bzip.org/1.0.5/bzip2-manual-1.0.5.html). Or use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/bzip2.html). Next time you might want to give Google a try...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Boost [iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) library, it can decompress bzip etc.